# How can do a tuple comparison in coffeescript similar to that in python?

Tags: coffeescript

This is a my function

```
st3 = (x, y) ->
  console.log "#{x?}, #{y?}"
  if [x?, y?] is [true, true]   # <- this is the line
    'good'
  'bad'
```

This is the output

```
true, true
bad
```

I want to be able to do a tuple comparison like it is in python.

In python, the `if` can be written roughly as

```
 if (x, y) == (True, False):
   return 'good'
```

The coffescript `if` loop is translated into javascript as such

```
if ([x != null, y != null] === [true, true]) {
  'good';
}
```

That's why this will not evaluated to true.

Is there any alternative way to express it in coffeescript?

Comment: can't you just use `if x is true and y is true`?

Comment: In this case for sure. But what if the tuple size grows? I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: there is nothing not elegant here, if you have arbitrary size of arguments, you can loop the arguments and evaluate the conditions. Or, you can write your own tuple prototypes and extend from there.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check to see if all of your arguments are not `None`, then I would do this:

```
def check_all(*args):
    return all(arg is not None for arg in args)
```

If you wanted to check if they're all `True` (like literally True) then you could use

```
def check_all(*args):
    return all(arg is True for arg in args)
```

If you wanted to take in a list (instead of variable number of parameters, remove the asterisk.